# Save data set with Dynamic columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have some excel in which the column names are numbers are dynamic, How can I design a table structure to save it in sql server table.

Since its dynamic I can't keep a specific table structure.Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL servers don't deal well with dynamic content, as they cant index it or create keys. Your best bet would be to use the XML or JSON data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly export the spreadsheet to SQL Server by checking the firstrow as column names. This will create the table with column names. 
Or
Export data into a different table with and identity seed and the first row will be having all the columns you needed. Generate a dynamic sql based on that and create the table, then import the data into the new table from the staging table by excluding the first row. But please note that the data type will not be proper as per your data. You may need to modify the datatypes and everything after analyzing the data.

Comment: There will be many excels with different columns, Suppose there are 100 excels should we create 100 tables.

Comment: The above method will help you to load the data into database with corresponding column headers. But after this you may need to design the tables accordingly. There may be common columns, so you will be able to maintain proper relationships as well. Write a package in SSIS and load the data into SQL Server. Process the data after that.